# How download package from unpkg or add in dependencies unpkg package?

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, unpkg

## problem

I try install ipfs from unpkg site.

- https://www.unpkg.com/browse/ipfs@0.36.3/

### Project

It is `React` project.

But i can't download this package or install in `package.json`

#### Main page unpkg

On main page write this

> unpkg is a fast, global content delivery network for everything on npm. Use it to quickly and easily load any file from any package using a URL like:
> unpkg.com/:package@:version/:file

### Solution

I try install

- package.json

> "ipfs": "unpkg.com/:ipfs@0.36.3"

- module

> import IPFS from 'https://unpkg.com/ipfs@0.36.3';

### it is not work.

How can i download from unpkg page this package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs#install-as-a-cli-user), you either need to install the package globally using following command

```
$ npm install -g ipfs
```

Or install `ipfs-core` as lighter package using following command.

```
$ npm install ipfs-core
```